# adjudge vs adjudicate vs judge (verbs)

Tags: difference, verbs, legalese

What are the similarities and differences?

> **[adjudge](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/adjudge) =** 1. Consider or declare to be true or the case:
>
> **adjudicate** = 1. Make a formal judgement on a disputed matter

I tried to read the etymology to see if anything shifted semantically, but I was confused because
http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=adjudge&allowed_in_frame=0 contains 'adiudicare', while http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=adjudicate&searchmode=none explicitly links to the previous link for 'adjudge'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Like many words in English, it has come to us by different ways. Although both originate in Latin according to etymonline, *adjudge* was taken from *French*, and *adjudicate* directly from Latin. I don't see much circular reasoning in the etymonline entries, since it only mentions that words are *related*. And a relationship between two words can of course be mentioned on both sides.
2. *Judge* is less formal, and less precise. I can judge something or someone, and it has absolutely no formal touch or legal impact. I judge your question, and based on my judgement I decide to answer or not. That informal sense of *judge* is used a lot and both other verbs cannot be used in that sense. The other way around, when I use any of the other two, I will make it very clear I mean the formal sense.

As to the difference between *adjudge* and *adjudicate*, it seems from the examples in the definition you link to that *adjudge* is about the resulting verdict:

> she was adjudged guilty
>   the court adjudged legal damages to her
>   the defaulter was adjudged to pay the whole amount

Whereas [adjudicate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/adjudicate) has these examples:

> the Committee adjudicates on all betting disputes
>   we asked him to adjudicate at the local flower show

So 'adjudicate' seems to refer to the act of judging a dispute or a situation, rather than the *result* of that act. However, it *can* be used to refer to the result as well:

> 1.2 [WITH OBJECT AND COMPLEMENT] Pronounce or declare judicially:
>   he was adjudicated bankrupt